# Python dictionary with base content

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am looking for the "good pythonic" way to define a dictionary with base elements. Let me explain:
I have a serie of key:value that configure my system. A group of key:value represent a configuration. Each configuration **must** have several common base elements. On the other hand each configuration has the possibility to define extra elements.

I could use python dictionaries but I do not think that could enforce the user to define "Mandatory_Elt_1" & "Mandatory_Elt_2" (or is it?):

```
Config_1 = { 'Mandatory_Elt_1':1,
             'Mandatory_Elt_2':2,
             'Optional_Elt_3':3 }

Config_2 = { 'Mandatory_Elt_1':5,
             'Mandatory_Elt_2':6,
             'Optional_Elt_4':7 }
```

A second option would be to subclass dict and define a specific constructor method where I would require the mandatory elements:

```
Config = MyDict( { 'Mandatory_Elt_1':5,
                   'Mandatory_Elt_2':6,
                   'Optional_Elt_4':7 } )
```

A third possibility would be to review the "input interface" such that other coders would not directly touch the base data. Instead, they would need to pass through a sanitization API. Or should I move to a databse based system altogether?

Are there any other alternatives? What would be the "lowest friction" way to force some elements to be defined in a dictionary?

Comment: Create the minimal dictionary yourself, then `update` it with the new elements?

Comment: The minimal dictionary has common keys but different values.

Comment: Yes, and when you `update` the new keys are added, the new values for existing keys replace the old ones and keys not in the new dictionary keep their default values. If there are keys you *must have* (that don't have defaults), their presence should be checked by whatever you're passing the resulting dictionary to.

Comment: I see, that is indeed a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need some mandatory elements in final dictionary,
you may use a basic dictionary and then update it with the user's dictionary.

E.g.

```
base_config = {'m1':1, 'm2': 2}
user_config = {'m1':3, 'new_param':4}

base_config.update(user_config)

final_config = base_config

>>> print final_config
{'new_param': 4, 'm1': 3, 'm2': 2}
```